# Servlet filter does not allow to upload a link to js library in jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, servlets

My filter just give access to the index.jsp. And index.jsp loaded but css and js lib does not work. When filter have dismissed lib works fine . Why? Should i give access to a folder with js and css?

filter

```
   public class LoginFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());

        if (path.equals("/") || path.equals("/index.jsp")){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp");
            servletRequest.setAttribute("message", "Добро пожаловать");
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        if (path.equals("/success.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/info.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/catalog.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/products.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/supplements.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/limitations.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/menu.jsp")
                ||path.equals("/info.jsp")
                ) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/"+path);
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        if (path.equals("/LoginServlet")){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/LoginServlet");
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        if (path.equals("/ProfileServlet")) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/ProfileServlet");
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        if (path.equals("/LogoutServlet")) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/LogoutServlet");
            dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        if (path.equals("/ButtonServlet")) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/ButtonServlet");
                dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                return;
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

index

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tabulator/tabulator.js"></script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>ProfileServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ProfileServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ProfileServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>ButtonServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ButtonServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>control.ButtonServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ButtonServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ButtonServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: It might make more sense if you can show the complete source for your filter so we can see what else it is doing? It sounds like maybe your filter is not allowing the filter chain to continue and the request is getting stuck in the filter?

Comment: I guess you're right. But i am new in this. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a call to

```
filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain)
```

which would allow the filter chain to continue, otherwise any other request pattern passing through that doesn't match the patterns you're trying to catch and handle will not pass through the filter to be handled as a request.

Here's a couple of useful links:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html